# How to read FrameBuffer from /dev/graphics/fb0 on ROOTED device (android 5.0)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, framebuffer, rooted-device

I'm try to read FrameBuffer from folder /dev/graphics/fb0 but I can't do that when I try below code:

```
fd = open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDWR)
```

But it always return **-1** , it means cannot read file fb0.
**Although I'm try above code on ROOTED device.**
My device is **Nexus 7** with **Android 5.0**

Could you please tell explain why it doen't worked?

So, have any other ways to read FramBuffer from /dev/graphics/fb0 or capture current screen in Native level?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Either your code isn't actually running as root, selinux is preventing even root from doing that, or you have no framebuffer device.  Even many devices which have one, don't expose a linear buffer which you can simply copy from, rather you have to get the GPU to export the data to you.  That's why adb long ago switched from doing screenshots itself to using a device-specific tool to encapsulate whatever is required.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - @ChrisStratton.
So, have any way to run my code as root?

Can you share me the way to get the GPU to export the data of screen?
Thank you very much!